# How to make reusable component using Isolated Scope in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am reading the article on  [Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and at the **Isolated Scope** section, I noticed

> As the name suggests, the isolate scope of the directive isolates
>   everything except models that you've explicitly added to the scope: {}
>   hash object. This is helpful when building reusable components because
>   it prevents a component from changing your model state except for the
>   models that you explicitly pass in.

So I tried the example

**Script.js**

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsIsolationExample', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.naomi = { name: 'Naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
    $scope.vojta = { name: 'Vojta', address: '3456 Somewhere Else' };
  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        customerInfo: '=info'
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-customer-plus-vojta.html'
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

Actually what I am looking for is that if

```
$scope.naomi = { name: 'Naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' }; 
$scope.vojta = { sex: 'Male', something: 'Something else' }
```

How can I print name,address (from naomi) and sex, something (from vojta)?

Comment: The example in the documentation works fine, and the html code is available. What don't you understand?

Comment: @JB Nizet, Respected Sir, As I understand that we can use the isolated scope for reusable component. But I am not clear as how to do something as  $scope.naomi = { name: 'Naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
    $scope.vojta = { sex: 'Male', something: 'Something else' };

Comment: Again: the example does that: it prints vojta or naomi, based on the directive parameter. You thus have a reusable directive that prints the user passed as parameter. What don't you understand in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/oGOPwTqISTYrP5fwBl4t?p=preview

HTML:

```
 <my-customer name="vojta.name" address="vojta.address"></my-customer>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        name: '=',
        address:'='
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-customer-plus-vojta.html'
    };
  });
```

Comment: Sir, what I am trying to do is this  $scope.naomi = { name: 'Naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' }; $scope.vojta = { sex: 'Male', something: 'Something else' }. How can i print this?

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar have you seen demo plunkr?

Comment: Yes Sir, and also I tried to edit as under app.js ( $scope.naomi = { x: 'Naomi', y: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
    $scope.vojta = { name: 'Vojta', address: '3456 Somewhere Else' };), index.html(<my-customer name="naomi.x" address="naomi.y"></my-customer>
    <my-customer name="vojta.name" address="vojta.address"></my-customer>), mycustomer-vojta.html(<h3>Customer</h3>
<p>Customer Name: {{name}}</p>
<p>Customer Address: {{address}}</p>
<p>Customer Address: {{x}}</p>), but no result... sorry if i am in the wrong way..please guide

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/oGOPwTqISTYrP5fwBl4t?p=preview

Comment: i believe that the Plunker server is down so the link is not opening. Could you please edit

Comment: Sir, i have posted another question by extending ur idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287895/problems-facing-while-working-on-isolated-scope-concept-of-angular

Comment: i have 1 more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404424/how-to-make-the-templateurl-that-will-load-the-html-template-at-runtime-based-on  could u please help