# Problems facing while working on Isolated Scope concept of Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to extend the example/answer (given by @sylwester) of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283892/how-to-make-reusable-component-using-isolated-scope-in-angularjs) I asked. Now I have to do something like this

[image]

**What I have done so far?**

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var arr1 = [
              {"EmpId":1,"EmpName":"Michale Sharma","gender":"Male","age":25,"salary":10000},
              {"EmpId":2,"EmpName":"Sunil Das","gender":"Male","age":24,"salary":5000},
              {"EmpId":3,"EmpName":"Robin Pandey","gender":"Male","age":35,"salary":45000},
              {"EmpId":4,"EmpName":"Mona Singh","gender":"Female","age":27,"salary":12000}

             ];
   var arr2 = [
                {"Deptid":4,"Deptname":"IT"},
                {"Deptid":1,"Deptname":"HR"},
                {"Deptid":3,"Deptname":"HW"},
                {"Deptid":2,"Deptname":"HW4"}
              ];

  var res = merge(arr1, arr2, "EmpId", "Deptid");

  $scope.Employee = {
    EmployeeName:res.EmpName,
    EmployeeSex:res.gender
  };

  $scope.Department = {
    DepartmentName:res.Deptname
  };

  //console.log(res);   

}).
directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        customer: '='

      },
      templateUrl: 'my-customer-plus-vojta.html'
    };

  });

  function merge(arr1, arr2, prop1, prop2) 
    {
        //alert("in merge");
        return arr1.map(function(item){
            var p = item[prop1];
            var el = arr2.filter(function(item) {
                return item[prop2] === p;
            });
            if (el.length === 0) {
                return null;
            }
            var res = {};
            for (var i in item) {
                if (i !== prop1) {
                    res[i] = item[i];
                }
            }
            for (var i1 in el[0]) {
                if (i1 !== prop2) {
                    res[i1] = el[0][i1];
                }
            }
            return res;
        }).filter(function(el){return el !== null;});
    }
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.3.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">       

    <table border="1">

      <tr>

        <td>EmployeeNames</td>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>Works For</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <my-customer customer="Employee"></my-customer>
        <my-customer customer="Department "></my-customer>

      </tr>

    </table>


  </body>

</html>
```

**my-customer-plus-vojta.html** (I am stuck here considering other things are correct. I equally know that li is not the correct way to use. However, I do not know what to do and how to do).

```
<h3>Employee-Department</h3>
<li ng-repeat="emp in customer.Employee">
<p ng-if="emp.EmployeeName">{{emp.EmployeeName}}</p>
<p ng-if="emp.EmployeeSex">{{emp.EmployeeSex}}</p>
</li>

<li ng-repeat="dept in customer.Department">
<p ng-if="dept.DepartmentName">{{dept.DepartmentName}}</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var arr1 = [{
      "EmpId": 1,
      "EmpName": "Michale Sharma",
      "gender": "Male",
      "age": 25,
      "salary": 10000
    }, {
      "EmpId": 2,
      "EmpName": "Sunil Das",
      "gender": "Male",
      "age": 24,
      "salary": 5000
    }, {
      "EmpId": 3,
      "EmpName": "Robin Pandey",
      "gender": "Male",
      "age": 35,
      "salary": 45000
    }, {
      "EmpId": 4,
      "EmpName": "Mona Singh",
      "gender": "Female",
      "age": 27,
      "salary": 12000
    }

  ];
  var arr2 = [{
    "Deptid": 4,
    "Deptname": "IT"
  }, {
    "Deptid": 1,
    "Deptname": "HR"
  }, {
    "Deptid": 3,
    "Deptname": "HW"
  }, {
    "Deptid": 2,
    "Deptname": "HW4"
  }];

  $scope.res = merge(arr1, arr2, "EmpId", "Deptid");
});
app.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      customer: '=myCustomer'

    },
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'customerTmpl.html',
    link: function(scope) {
      console.log(scope)
    }
  };
});

function merge(arr1, arr2, prop1, prop2) {
  //alert("in merge");
  return arr1.map(function(item) {
    var p = item[prop1];
    var el = arr2.filter(function(item) {
      return item[prop2] === p;
    });
    if (el.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    var res = {};
    for (var i in item) {
      if (i !== prop1) {
        res[i] = item[i];
      }
    }
    for (var i1 in el[0]) {
      if (i1 !== prop2) {
        res[i1] = el[0][i1];
      }
    }
    return res;
  }).filter(function(el) {
    return el !== null;
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="customer in res" my-customer="customer"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


  <script type="text/ng-template" id="customerTmpl.html">
    <tr>
      <td>{{customer.EmpName}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.gender}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.age}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.salary}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.Deptname}}</td>
    </tr>
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: i have 1 more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404424/how-to-make-the-templateurl-that-will-load-the-html-template-at-runtime-based-on  could u please help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you can't just link to `res.EmpName`... **Your `res` variable is an Array of Objects**. You need to loop through that Array, then look inside that Object to grab what you need.  Then, you can supply it as a part of your $scope key/value.

For example the 1st key of your `res` object:

```
Deptname: "HR"
EmpName: "Michale Sharma"
age: 25
gender: "Male"
salary: 10000
```

Create empty arrays for your new collections you need to make, then loop through the res object and add them to it.

```
var empNames = [],
    empGenders = [],
    empDepts = [];

for (key in res) {
    empNames.push(res[key].EmpName);
    empGenders.push(res[key].gender);
    empDepts.push(res[key].Deptname);
}

// NOW you can apply them into your scope

$scope.Employee = {
    EmployeeName : empNames,
    EmployeeSex : empGenders
};

$scope.Department = {
    DepartmentName : empDepts
};
```

Comment: I just changed the way u asked in app.js. Where else i need to change? pls let me know