# How to make the templateURL that will load the HTML template at runtime based on the data passed?

Tags: angularjs

I am following the example of [Template-expanding directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

[image]

It is working fine. Now I am trying to extend the concept as follows.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {  

    var EmpData = [{
      "EmpId": 1,
      "EmpName": "Michale Sharma"
    }, {
      "EmpId": 2,
      "EmpName": "Sunil Das"
    }
  ];
  var DeptData= [{
    "Deptid": 4,
    "Deptname": "IT"
  }, {
    "Deptid": 1,
    "Deptname": "HR"
  }];

    $scope.customer = {
      EmployeeRelatedData: EmpData,
      DepartmentRelatedData: DeptData
    }; 
});

app.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
      return attr.type+'.html';
    }
  };
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />       
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.3.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>   
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">  

    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <!-- Section for Employee -->
      <div my-customer type="EmployeeRelatedData">

        <table border="1">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Employee Id</th>
                  <th>Employee Name</th>                 
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in customer.EmployeeRelatedData"></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table> 

        </div>

      <!-- Section for Department -->
      <div my-customer type="DepartmentRelatedData">

        <table border="1">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Department Id</th>
                  <th>Department Name</th>                 
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in customer.DepartmentRelatedData"></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>        

      </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**EmployeeRelatedData.html**

```
<tr>
      <td>{{customer.EmpId}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.EmpName}}</td>     
</tr>
```

**DepartmentRelatedData.html**

```
<tr>
      <td>{{customer.Deptid}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.Deptname}}</td>     
</tr>
```

I am looking for the output

[image]

What is the mistake that I am making for which I am not able to get it?
Thanks.

Comment: there are not `td` inside `tr`, where do u expect to see the data...

Comment: so how to do it...what changes i need to make..if u can help me i will be grateful... i am trying it for a long time...but could not get it to work

Comment: create a plunkr... provide the link to play with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got few mistakes please see here for working demo

http://plnkr.co/edit/RQ1xWaLUAsBpNgyMWujI?p=preview

```
my-customer should be inside tr tag not before table
```

you need to pass your customer to directive scope so in you can do that by crating isolate scope

```
 scope: {

      customer: '=myCustomer'
    },
```

and in your view

```
my-customer="x"
```

as x is your customer

Comment: Hi @sylwester, thanks for the help..but the output/display part is not as per the way, I am looking for...

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar I'm affraid you can't put 2 ng-repeters into one row to get table like on your example, you can merge your data in controller or style tables with css to get that result please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/RQ1xWaLUAsBpNgyMWujI?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot...more things to learn from you. I will try in another way;if i get stuck i will let you know. I will basically try to follow the way u have shown.Seriously u have helped me a lot so far.